# Locale in PHP for multi language site

Tags: php

Im new to PHP and im building a site that need to be with multi language support, can some one tell me is there any best functions to achieve/convert one language content to another in php?

Comment: Use utf-8 encoding and multibyte functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: The standard tool for *localization* is [gettext](http://php.net/gettext), http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/. You may or may not like it. L10n is hard; do some research.

Comment: notwithstanding the other comments the best results would be from a human performed translation

Comment: use Yii MVC; you only have to set arrays with key => value for each language

Answer (score 1):

Well: *"How long is a piece of string?"* comes to my mind as a similar question. ;-)

No, basically you need to parameterize all your messages and text content and make it available in both languages. This can be done by having two (possibly associative) arrays between which you can switch using a language key (in this example it is the first index: `0`:English, `1`:German):

For example:

```
$msg=array( // first language English
           array( 'login'->'Please enter your user name',
                  'bye'->'Thank you for visiting this site').
            // then a second language (German)
           array( 'login'->'Bitte egeben Sie Ihren Benutzernamen ein',
                  'bye'->'Vielen Dank für Ihren Besuch')
            // and possibly other languages to follow ..
        //,array( 'login'->'...'),'bye'->'...')
           );
```

Comment: Key-value array translations are workable only for the most simple of cases. Once you start outsourcing your translations to translators or just other people you work with, you need more tools to handle the actual process: an automated extractor, a merge tool and two-way commenting is kind of the minimum; additionally you'll want domains, context and categories (to use gettext parlance) to organize your translations.

Comment: @deceze Very true. And, yes, in larger projects you will need to have all language data organized in one or several database tables. For outsourcing translations it is very often necessary to have the translator see the whole web page (or at least relevant screenshots thereof), so they can properly understand the context. This is very often forgotten and can lead to ridiculous results.

Comment: A *database* is not necessary, files will do just fine. But yes, in translations *the process* is often more important than *the implementation* and you need a toolchain that properly supports languages and their finicky differences and humans dealing with code and words.

Comment: @deceze Your arguments may be true for larger applications, but for those little hobby-projects that we all have this simple method is still valid.

Comment: @Zim Until your "little hobby project" grows... Suddenly you translate into just one more language and your work load exponentially increases because you have to handle everything manually... Suddenly you realize you need a robust pluralization tool... :) It's not that hard to use the proper tools from the beginning; just get used to them once.